# Unable to set ViewModel on Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

New to Kotlin language, trying Android [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html). Trying to set a `ViewModel` for my `LifecycleActivity` in Kotlin language:

```
class FooActivity : LifecycleActivity() {
  private var mViewModel: FooViewModel? = null
  ..
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FooViewModel.class) <-- error here
```

Getting *Name expected:* and *expecting )*

What am I missing?

Comment: FooViewModel::class.java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class usage is wrong. With Kotlin you use: `FooViewModel::class.java`